# Google Custom Search API: Using it as a scraper?

Tags: api

Is this API simply for searching your website only, or can any standard google search (even advanced search features) be submitted to it? I understand there is a limit of 100 per day, I am just curious if it can be invoked from say your own machine as the code samples and introduction indicate its intended use is for displaying results on your website. I want to search outside of a given domain and scrape standard google results for any given search. This will not be an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

My current understanding:

- You're limited to 100/day only if you don't pay.
- You do have to specify domains, but some tlds are fine (eg: .uk)
- There's a limit to 100 search results for any given search query (ten pages of up to ten responses)
- It can be invoked from your own machine.